# How is it that main function is always loaded at the same address whereas variables have different address most of the time?

Tags: c, linux, virtualization, memory-address, relocation

I wrote this small program today and I was blown away by the results. Here is the program

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int a;
 printf("\n\tMain is located at: %p and the variable a is located at address: %p",main,&a);
 return 0;
}
```

on my machine the main function is always loaded at address "0x80483d4" and the address of the variable keeps on varying How does this happen? I read in operating systems that as a part of virtualization scheme the OS keeps relocating the address of instructions. So why is it that everytime I run this program that main is loaded at the same address?

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization . I think that the address of entrypoint is not randomized.

Comment: @pmg: +1 for that xkcd linky... :)

Comment: I added another "user defined function" into this code and suprisingly it is also loaded at the same address between consecutive executions. I ran the compiled program 4 times and this new function was loaded at "0x80483d4" everytime I executed the program!!

Comment: Maybe it would help if you told us what Operating System you're trying that program on? ??? DOS? VMS? Symbian?

Comment: OMG sorry!! I am using arch linux kernel version "2.6.35-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT" and I used gcc version 4.5.1 (GCC) to compile the program using "gcc --std=gnu99 -o op address.c" Oh and I am executing the binary in "konsole"

Comment: Function addresses cannot be randomized without impacting performance significantly (building in "PIE" mode is necessary). Randomizing the start of the stack has no cost, and is done by default on modern operating systems. If you tried a global variable, you'd find that its address will not change either.

Comment: Wow yes it does not!! So is this address decided during compile time itself? If yes what would happen if the pre-determined slot in the memory were not available? Like if the location is already occupied by another program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On ELF systems such as Linux, the addresses at which the segments of normal executable files (ELF type `ET_EXEC`) load are fixed at compile time.  Shared objects (ELF type `ET_DYN`) such as libraries are built to be position-independent, with their segments loadable anywhere in the address space (potentially with some restrictions on some architectures).  It is possible to build executables such that they are actually `ET_DYN` -- these are known as "position-independent executables" (PIE), but is not a common technique.

What you are seeing is the fact that your `main()` function is in the fixed-address text segment of your compiled executable.  Try also printing the address of a library function such as `printf()` after locating it via `dlsym()` -- if your system does support and have enabled address space layout randomization (ASLR), then you should see the address of that function change from run to run of your program.  (If you just print the address of the library function by putting the reference directly in your code, what you may actually get is the address of the function's procedure lookup table (PLT) trampoline, which is statically compiled at a fixed address in your executable.)

The variable you see change address from run-to-run because it is an automatic variable created on the stack, not in statically allocated memory.  Depending on OS and version, the address of the base of the stack may shift from run to run even without ASLR.  If you move the variable declaration to be a global outside of your function, you see it behave the same way your `main()` function does.

Here's a full example -- compile with something like `gcc -o example example.c -dl`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int a = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int b = 0;
    void *handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("&main: %p; &a: %p\n", &main, &a);
    printf("&printf: %p; &b: %p\n", dlsym(handle, "printf"), &b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does! Wow you have cleared lots of things. One question still remains in my mind though, let us suppose that after compilation a function func() is to be loaded at address "X" in the memory, now what if before execution this location "X" were to be occupied by some other program? What would happen in that case? Will the program be relocated? Will it have to wait?

Comment: In most contemporary OSes, the kernel provides every process its own virtual address space.  As far as each different process is concerned, it has the entire range of addresses available user context to itself.  This prevents the accidental collision you describe, and also prevents programs from maliciously interfering with each other.   And if you like my answer, please upvote and accept :-).

Comment: Oh yes! How could I forget that? HAHAHAHAHA thanks a lot man you have cleared up every inch of doubt! Props!

Answer (score 0):

`main(...)` is a runtime start-up library code in which the operating system loads and executes each time. Have a look at the CRT (C Runtime Library) which would contain the code to do this depending on your compiler.

Another thing to bear in mind, that address - I would not worry about it too much as long as the C code works. That is a fluke pattern, by order of dependant on a number of factors such as OS load, drivers used, hardware, AntiVirus software etc...

Also, in relation to the code, if you add static variables, functions, pointers, that will change the layout of the binary code, **and** more *importantly*, the addresses of those symbols that gets loaded at run-time, will be different.

Comment: Hello! I have added another user defined function into the same program and it is also loaded at the same memory address between consecutive executions of the program! Oh and I executed the program more than 4-5 times. The address of the functions changes once I recompile the code but after that it sticks to the new value! Strange isn't it?

Comment: The CRT is interesting, but not relevant here -- `main()` is defined in the provided code.