# ASLR and addresses

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, assembly, memory-address

Have a look at this main:

```
int 
main() 
{
  int asd = 10;
  printf("%p\n", &asd);
  return 0;
}
```

Address of asd at at a given moment:

```
0x7ffff5f7c16c
```

Address of main (always the same):

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x00000000004005b4 <+0>:    push   %rbp
```

Why the addresses of the variables, of a regular c program, change at every execution, whereas the starting address of the program itself it is always the same (assuming that it is not position independent)? 
I see that the address variability is due to the ASLR mode, but why it does affect only the program variables, and does not affect where the code is allocated? Is this related to the fact that as being the code section ro it doesn't make sense randomizing it when not strictly necessary?

Furthermore, why is there an enormous gap between the tarting address of the main and the address of the variable asd?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is it that main function is always loaded at the same address whereas variables have different address most of the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699845/how-is-it-that-main-function-is-always-loaded-at-the-same-address-whereas-variab)

Comment: The question is the same, but what I am looking for is slightly different. I'd like to know why there is this difference between the text section and the stack, what could be the reason (if any), not why it is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) happens mostly at [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) time. The stack segment of the main thread is allocated at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time (of your program) -but may be "randomly" located. The initial stack pointer of your `main` also depends on various factors (notably your environment - see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)).

The stack pointer is set at `execve` time. It is passed to the [`crt0.o`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) startup object file (which calls your `main`) by conventions defined in e.g. the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) specifications.

The address of `main` is fixed inside the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file. Unless your code is [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (i.e. compiled with `-fPIE` or `-fPIC` etc...), it cannot be moved (because that would require specific [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29)). Use `objdump -f badnack` on your `badnack` executable to find out. Also `pmap` on your process. And PIC has a small cost (It uses more registers).

Comment: I see, but assuming that the program is not position independent, why the stack may be randomly allocated while the main is not?

Comment: Because to move `main` would require relocation of the code.

Comment: Why the stack is moved then?

Comment: It is not *moved*, it is *randomly* initialized at `execve` time.